# Docker-Compose for local Spring Boot Development

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file setup along with an associated Dockerfile.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
   vault:   
   springboot-app:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
       - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD

COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/

WORKDIR /build/

RUN mvn -B -U -e clean verify 

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

My application is now running fine when I run docker-compose up.
I was wondering what change do I need to make in order to have the spring boot app rebuild upon code changes? In my pom file, I have the spring-boot-maven-plugin setup as follows and I have specified the spring-boot-devtools dependency

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated on this

Thanks
Damien

Comment: Do you use git ? Github/gitlab ? Then use CI/CD

Comment: Do you want to rebuild the image upon a code changes in your repo?

Comment: I want to run my spring boot app locally using docker-compose, not concerned with recreating the image, just want to use docker compose to start all dependencies and also be able to see live changes in my app

Comment: I'd recommend running everything _but_ your app in Docker, making sure all of the dependencies have published `ports:`, and setting up a Spring profile that points at all `http://localhost:...` addresses for the dependencies.  Then from your IDE's point of view you're running totally normal local code, but you still get the benefits of Docker for things like application-specific database engines.

Comment: I think one issue, if I understood the problem right, is that you are copying the whole data source to the container so, unless you develop inside the container (at the end, it would also be problematic since you would lose changes made inside the container) the container is not aware of any changes to the source code. You could instead use a `volume`, this way, changes to the local source code are "seem" by the container too.

Comment: cool will try the volumes and let you know how I get on with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might not be answer but

do you have any specific use case to use 2 docker images within DockerFile.? 
If, You can move out the build steps from dockerfile and build(invoke build) from script and invoke docker-compose to copy the build to docker container and start the container. 
You may hit issue while COPY, docker takes docker folder rather than your project folder.

Comment: Its a best practice I found on a few websites to limit the size of the overall image

Comment: I have never tried that, i think it will be 2 different docker images and both will have different context.

Answer (score 7):

For production applications you can use a Java Docker image along with the compiled .jar file.

For local development use a [Maven Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) instead. It can run the source code and compile whenever you make a change to the application. You can use a docker-compose.yml file such as:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  backend:
    image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-8
    command: mvn spring-boot:run
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/mymaven:rw
    working_dir: /usr/src/mymaven
```

Be sure to set the volumes to map your source code to the Docker container, and to set the work directory for Maven to find your pom.xml.